# Failed to fetch plugin github:razorpay/razorpay-cordova via registry

Tags: cordova-plugins, ionic6

I'm getting error while adding the razorpay-cordova plugin in ionic 6 project. I have added my `ionic info` and `error`. I even tried to add it via local folder but got similar

```html
ionic cordova plugin add D:\SAM\Fantasy\razorpay-cordova --f
> cordova.cmd plugin add D:\SAM\Fantasy\razorpay-cordova
Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @angular/cdk@12.1.1
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@11.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"11.2.14" from @angular/forms@11.2.14
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!     peer @angular/forms@">=8.2.7" from @ionic/angular@5.6.10
npm ERR!     node_modules/@ionic/angular
npm ERR!       @ionic/angular@"^5.5.2" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/forms@"^11.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@9.1.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!       @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"^9.1.3" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"11.2.14" from @angular/platform-browser@11.2.14
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
npm ERR!     peer @angular/platform-browser@"11.2.14" from @angular/forms@11.2.14
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!       peer @angular/forms@">=8.2.7" from @ionic/angular@5.6.10
npm ERR!       node_modules/@ionic/angular
npm ERR!         @ionic/angular@"^5.5.2" from the root project
npm ERR!       2 more (@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap, the root project)
npm ERR!     peer @angular/platform-browser@"11.2.14" from @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@11.2.14
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic
npm ERR!       @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@"~11.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     2 more (@angular/router, the root project)
npm ERR!   9 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^12.0.0 || ^13.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@12.1.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!   peer @angular/cdk@">=8.0.0" from ngx-sharebuttons@8.0.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/ngx-sharebuttons
npm ERR!     ngx-sharebuttons@"^8.0.5" from the root project
npm ERR!   @angular/cdk@"^12.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@13.3.11
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^12.0.0 || ^13.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@12.1.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!     peer @angular/cdk@">=8.0.0" from ngx-sharebuttons@8.0.5
npm ERR!     node_modules/ngx-sharebuttons
npm ERR!       ngx-sharebuttons@"^8.0.5" from the root project
npm ERR!     @angular/cdk@"^12.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\spal\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\spal\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-09-07T07_25_02_472Z-debug-0.log
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\spal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:136:25)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\spal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1093:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5) {
  stderr: 'npm ERR! code ERESOLVE\n' +
    'npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve\n' +
    'npm ERR! \n' +
    'npm ERR! While resolving: @angular/cdk@12.1.1\n' +
    'npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@11.2.14\n' +
    'npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common\n' +
    'npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"11.2.14" from @angular/forms@11.2.14\n' +
    'npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/forms\n' +
    'npm ERR!     peer @angular/forms@">=8.2.7" from @ionic/angular@5.6.10\n' +
    'npm ERR!     node_modules/@ionic/angular\n' +
    'npm ERR!       @ionic/angular@"^5.5.2" from the root project\n' +
    'npm ERR!     peer @angular/forms@"^11.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@9.1.3\n' +
    'npm ERR!     node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap\n' +
    'npm ERR!       @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"^9.1.3" from the root project\n' +
    'npm ERR!     1 more (the root project)\n' +
    'npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"11.2.14" from @angular/platform-browser@11.2.14\n' +
    'npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/platform-browser\n' +
    'npm ERR!     peer @angular/platform-browser@"11.2.14" from @angular/forms@11.2.14\n' +
    'npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/forms\n' +
    'npm ERR!       peer @angular/forms@">=8.2.7" from @ionic/angular@5.6.10\n' +
    'npm ERR!       node_modules/@ionic/angular\n' +
    'npm ERR!         @ionic/angular@"^5.5.2" from the root project\n' +
    'npm ERR!       2 more (@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap, the root project)\n' +
    'npm ERR!     peer @angular/platform-browser@"11.2.14" from @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@11.2.14\n' +
    'npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic\n' +
    'npm ERR!       @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@"~11.2.0" from the root project\n' +
    'npm ERR!     2 more (@angular/router, the root project)\n' +
    'npm ERR!   9 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, ...)\n' +
    'npm ERR! \n' +
    'npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:\n' +
    'npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^12.0.0 || ^13.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@12.1.1\n' +
    'npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/cdk\n' +
    'npm ERR!   peer @angular/cdk@">=8.0.0" from ngx-sharebuttons@8.0.5\n' +
    'npm ERR!   node_modules/ngx-sharebuttons\n' +
    'npm ERR!     ngx-sharebuttons@"^8.0.5" from the root project\n' +
    'npm ERR!   @angular/cdk@"^12.1.1" from the root project\n' +
    'npm ERR! \n' +
    'npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@13.3.11\n' +
    'npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common\n' +
    'npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^12.0.0 || ^13.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@12.1.1\n' +
    'npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/cdk\n' +
    'npm ERR!     peer @angular/cdk@">=8.0.0" from ngx-sharebuttons@8.0.5\n' +
    'npm ERR!     node_modules/ngx-sharebuttons\n' +
    'npm ERR!       ngx-sharebuttons@"^8.0.5" from the root project\n' +
    'npm ERR!     @angular/cdk@"^12.1.1" from the root project\n' +
    'npm ERR! \n' +
    'npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry\n' +
    'npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps\n' +
    'npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.\n' +
    'npm ERR! \n' +
    'npm ERR! See C:\\Users\\spal\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.\n' +
    '\n' +
    'npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:\n' +
    'npm ERR!     C:\\Users\\spal\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_logs\\2022-09-07T07_25_02_472Z-debug-0.log\n',
  code: 1
}
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd plugin add D:\SAM\Fantasy\razorpay-cordova exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

error.

```css
 ionic cordova plugin add com.razorpay.cordova --f
> cordova.cmd plugin add com.razorpay.cordova
Failed to fetch plugin github:razorpay/razorpay-cordova via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
CordovaError: Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:   
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @angular/cdk@12.1.1
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@11.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"11.2.14" from @angular/forms@11.2.14     
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!     peer @angular/forms@">=8.2.7" from @ionic/angular@5.6.10
npm ERR!     node_modules/@ionic/angular
npm ERR!       @ionic/angular@"^5.5.2" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/forms@"^11.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@9.1.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!       @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"^9.1.3" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"11.2.14" from @angular/platform-browser@11.2.14
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
npm ERR!     peer @angular/platform-browser@"11.2.14" from @angular/forms@11.2.14
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!       peer @angular/forms@">=8.2.7" from @ionic/angular@5.6.10
npm ERR!       node_modules/@ionic/angular
npm ERR!         @ionic/angular@"^5.5.2" from the root project
npm ERR!       2 more (@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap, the root project)
npm ERR!     peer @angular/platform-browser@"11.2.14" from @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@11.2.14
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic
npm ERR!       @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@"~11.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     2 more (@angular/router, the root project)
npm ERR!   9 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^12.0.0 || ^13.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@12.1.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!   peer @angular/cdk@">=8.0.0" from ngx-sharebuttons@8.0.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/ngx-sharebuttons
npm ERR!     ngx-sharebuttons@"^8.0.5" from the root project
npm ERR!   @angular/cdk@"^12.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@13.3.11
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^12.0.0 || ^13.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@12.1.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!     peer @angular/cdk@">=8.0.0" from ngx-sharebuttons@8.0.5
npm ERR!     node_modules/ngx-sharebuttons
npm ERR!       ngx-sharebuttons@"^8.0.5" from the root project
npm ERR!     @angular/cdk@"^12.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\spal\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\spal\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-09-07T06_41_40_704Z-debug-0.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

    cordova.cmd plugin add com.razorpay.cordova exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

```html
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.20.1 (C:\Users\spal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.6.10
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1102.19
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 11.2.14
   @angular/cli                  : 11.2.14
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 7.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 11.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 9.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 18 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed globally
   native-run  : 1.4.0

System:

   NodeJS : v16.17.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 8.15.0
   OS     : Windows 10
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution. I removed the git link of Razorpay in package.json and changed it to a version. That's it.

```html
"com.razorpay.cordova": "^1.4.5",
```